# Влияют ли неиспользуемые объявления и определения на сборку проекта?

Tags: c++, функции, компиляция, сборка, компоновщик

Влияют ли неиспользуемые объявления и определения на бинарь/скорость компиляции/линковки/что-либо ещё? Интересно, если какой-то TU использует из хедера только 1 функцию из тысячи, имеет ли смысл выделить эту функцию в отдельный хедер, чтобы не обрабатывать 999 ненужных?

```
void foo(); // попадёт ли этот foo в бинарь? уменьшится ли скорость компиляции/линковки?

int main() {
  return 42;
}
```

```cpp
void foo() {} // а теперь?

int main() {
  return 42;
}
```

Comment: Все что не используется, выкидывается. Если стоит оптимизация.

Comment: @ori но получается, что это влияет на время компиляции тогда

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void foo();` точно никуда не попадает, потому что там нечему попадать. Но компиляцию наверное чуть-чуть замедляет, просто потому, что компилятору нужно переварить больше кода.

`void foo() {}` влияет и на время компиляции, и на время линковки тоже, потому что выкидыванием лишних функций занимается линковщик (если они имеют external linkage, т.е. не static снаружи классов/функций, т.е. видны в других единицах трансляции).

Может потребоваться включить какие-то оптимизации. Во втором примере я получил одинаковый размер бинарей только с флагом `-s`.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу размера бинаря:
маленький тест.

Компилировал командой `gcc main.cpp` (`mingw`). Получил следующие результаты:
1 вариант - 41,549 байт

```
void foo();

int main() {
  return 42;
}
```

2 вариант -> 42,079 байт

```
void foo() {}

int main() {
  return 42;
}
```

3 вариант -> 41,549 байт

```
int main() {
  return 42;
}
```

Как видно из примеров выше без оптимизаций получаем следующую картину:

1. определенные функции (пусть и пустым телом) "попадают" в бинарь.
2. объявленные функции, но не определенные не попадают в бинарь.

Comment: VC++ во всех трех случаях дал один и тот же размер...